# Changing primary key value for a database row

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am using SQL Server Management Studio and I want to change an auto increment primary key value of a table row, with a different value. SQL Server Management Studio after opening the table for edit, shows this field grayed for all rows, of course.

Is it possible? I want to use the number of a row we deleted by mistake, therefore it's valid (there is no conflict with other primary key values) and - most important of all - the next row added in the DB should have an intact auto incremented value.

Thanks.

EDIT: losing the link with other table records on this PK is not an issue for this row. We can restore it manually.

Comment: Don't use primary keys as gap free ranking numbers or something like that.

Comment: @juergend you cannot emphasise this enough. I suggest this should be the answer!

Comment: I need quickly recover this situation for a business database. If you are recommending a different design approach, I appreciate it but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: As far as I know there's no other way to do this than to copy the values to another column, modify them, drop the original column, and reseed the identity counter on new column. But with PK on it, it's not a viable option (references from other tables to PK, I assume). The fact that you need to perform this operation means that there are some design flaws in your process / db structure :).

Comment: select the records in temp table - update the temp table in order to fix the order - drop and create the original table - insert records from the temp table in the new table

Comment: You cannot update the value of an `IDENTITY` column - you can only set it explicitly on `INSERT` if you really must.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not necessarily recommended but, insert a copy of the row where you want to change the number, but with the ID you require:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT aTable ON
GO

-- Attempt to insert an explicit ID value of 3
INSERT INTO aTable (id, product) VALUES(3, 'blah')       
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT aTable OFF
GO
```

Then delete the row with the number you don't want (after you update any FK references).

More details here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx

---

For posterity, to clarify the question in the comment below, the auto increment value will only be affected if you insert a value greater than the current maximum.

Quoting from linked article:

> If the value inserted is larger than the current identity value for
>   the table, SQL Server automatically uses the new inserted value as the
>   current identity value.

Comment: It works on my backup copy of the database table! Will this affect the next auto increment value? If not it's the solution I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

## Do not do this!

What you are trying to do is actually a SQL antipattern.

Even a deleted ID contains information (i.e., that a record has been deleted), and you should therefore not reuse IDs. Moreover, if the old ID is still referenced in another table (or in the notebook of the old-fashioned guy next door), troubled waters are ahead.

*I highly recommended the book [SQL Antipatterns](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns/). It contains a more detailed description of this antipattern (as well as lots of others). Note: I am not affiliated with the authors of that book.*